# How to get number of days between current date and a particular day in past in unix ksh?

Tags: date, unix, days

Lets say I want to get number of days past 1st Jan 2016 in Unix (KSH)

Comment: Edited the question to clearly explain what OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: To get number of days from 2016-01-01 till date, use

```
echo $(( ( $(date +'%s') - $(date -ud '2016-01-01 00:00:00' +'%s') )/60/60/24 ))
117
```

Comment: sorry If I was not clear about my question but I want the days in result

Comment: Edited the answer. Check and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: thanks that is what I want but is there any more simpler way , I mean a direct command or an option in the date command itself  ?

Comment: Here we are converting both dates to unix time, subtracting them and then dividing to get date. The command may look big but it is pretty straight forward. However I am not denying that this cannot be done in a `direct` way. But I couldn't find any option in date command to do so.

Comment: If the answer worked for you then please accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

`date` utility is able to compute adjustement:

```
date -v +10d -j 0101000016
```

will computes the date 10 days after 01/01/2016.

Comment: I tried it but is it is not working, some thing working on linux will also help